# Perplexity increasing on Test DataSet in LDA (Topic Modelling)

Tags: r, clustering, text-mining, topic-model, lda

I was plotting the perplexity values on LDA models (R) by varying topic numbers. Already train and test corpus was created.

Unfortunately, perplexity is increasing with increased number of topics on test corpus. I am not sure whether it is natural, but i have read perplexity value should decrease as we increase the number of topics.

Also, i plotted perplexity on train corpus and it is decreasing as topic number is increased. I am not sure whether it represent over-fitting of my model.

Please help me understand

**Perplexity on Train Data**
[image]

**Perplexity on Test Data**
[image]

Comment: It looks very much like overfitting or a stupid mistake in preprocessing of your texts. Could you test your modelling pipeline on some publicly accessible dataset and show us the code?

Comment: I feel its because of sampling mistake i made while taking training and test set. Let me shuffle them properly and execute. Will update